# how to split and filter a string?

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

Consider this character

```
mystring <- "this, this and this, and this, and this."
```

I want to split on `,` or `and` but I want to get rid of the empty strings. I am puzzled by the fact that my solution below does not work

splitting works OK

```
> str_split(mystring, regex(',|and'))
[[1]]
[1] "this"   " this " " this"  " "      " this"  " "      " this."
```

filtering does not work

```
> str_split(mystring, regex(',|and')) %>% purrr::keep(., function(x) x!= '')
Error: Predicate functions must return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a logical vector of length 7
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

What is the issue here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we return only blank (`""`) instead of spaces (`" "`), then we can make use of `nzchar`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
str_split(mystring, regex('\\s*,\\s*|\\s*and\\s*'))[[1]]  %>%
    keep(nzchar)
[1] "this"  "this"  "this"  "this"  "this."
```

---

If we are using the OP's code, use `trimws` before the `keep` step

```
str_split(mystring, regex(',|and')) %>%
    pluck(1) %>%
    trimws %>%
    keep(nzchar) 
[1] "this"  "this"  "this"  "this"  "this."
```

---

In the OP's code, the `keep` didn't work because the object from `str_split` is a `list` and the element was not extracted.  Thus, when we apply the function, it returns multiple TRUE/FALSE for the single `list` element whereas `keep` expects a single TRUE/FALSE.  Here, we are `pluck`ing the list element.  In the first solution, extraction was done by `[[1]]`

Comment: thanks! what is I want to get rid of blank or spaces?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I didn't get your question.  Are you looking for split without returning any spaces